# Add two different adapters to one listView in java

Tags: java, android

I want to join two adapter into a one list view in a single page.

```
LoanApplicationAdapter adapter = new LoanApplicationAdapter(this, R.layout.item_loan, customerLoanApplicationList);
```

```
LoanAdapter adapter = new LoanAdapter(this, R.layout.item_loan,customerLoanList);
        binding.listLoan.setAdapter(adapter);
```

above customerLoanApplicationList and customerLanList want to show in a one List view in my android application.Can you tell how can I do it.

Comment: RecyclerView does supports [ConcateAdapter](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) . AFAIK `ListView` does not .

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is, you can create two view Holders in one adapter.
By doing so you can Implement different logic for different view holders and it will be more easier and accurate.

(Preferred to use RecyclerView)